# Why doesn't Wayward Pines wait a more couple of thousands of years?

Tags: plot-explanation, wayward-pines

Near the year 4028, David Pilcher and the future citizens of Wayward Pines wake up from a cryogenic sleep. My question is pretty straightforward.

If the world is currently ruled by monstrous creatures (mutated humans), why doesn't David Pilcher decide to go back to a cryogenic sleep and wait a more couple of thousands of year, just to see how the world evolves?

Comment: Personally, I think if society has devolved this dramatically in 2000 years, it is on a clear downward slide, and Pilcher probably believes so too. Nothing outside has proved to have even the potential for a rise in evolution. He could have to leapfrog potentially into forever in hops of 2000 years. I'm not sure the cryogenic tubes he has are made for repeated, or incremental usage. I don't think the show has said whether they are one usage tubes and fully consumed in the process.

Comment: @wbogacz In the last episode (episode 8?), David Pilcher sends one guy of the team to a cryogenic sleep, so I'm thinking it's not one usage tube.

Comment: He intended Reggie to be stored as punishment, and permanent, without design to re-emerge. He could as well have put him in a barrel. There is no tube-worthiness-guarantee to be inferred there.

Comment: CJ Mitchum tried to warn Pilcher with evidence collected every score years for thousand of years, but clearly Pilcher suffers from a mental disorder and wanted to fight

Comment: That was just one problem I had with the idea - if humans are doomed to "devolve" in such a way, then what's the point of preserving a group of humans?  They'll just devolve eventually too.  Maybe they waived it away on the show that the people selected had better genes or something, but the book never did.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few factors here - there was no reason to believe that the creatures would be gone in another thousand years, or even ten thousand years. There would, however, probably be an upper limit on how long the cryogenic tubes would last. Further, if you just have a blanket 'wake us up in 50,000 years', you might wake up to an ice age, or a radically different earth (ex. different oxygen levels).

Bottom line, *at some point* you have to wake up and make due. If you can deal with the creatures, then it doesn't matter *when* you wake up, just assume they will be there.